# Single word full text search is slow in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

When running a full text search in PostgreSQL, the performance is exceedingly slow when searching for a single word. Why?

In a large table of posts, a full text search on the `title` field performs quickly if searching on at least two words (even the same word duplicated, as in "yorkie yorkie"):

```sql
explain analyze
SELECT * FROM "posts"
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', posts.title) @@ websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'yorkie yorkie')
ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

Output:

```
QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=299.53..299.69 rows=63 width=712) (actual time=2.812..3.003 rows=56 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=299.53..299.69 rows=63 width=712) (actual time=2.797..2.887 rows=56 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 61kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=32.49..297.65 rows=63 width=712) (actual time=1.293..2.277 rows=56 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, (title)::text) @@ '''yorkie'' & ''yorkie'''::tsquery)
               Heap Blocks: exact=56
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on posts_title_simple_gin  (cost=0.00..32.47 rows=63 width=0) (actual time=1.105..1.109 rows=56 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, (title)::text) @@ '''yorkie'' & ''yorkie'''::tsquery)
 Planning Time: 2.324 ms
 Execution Time: 3.700 ms
```

However, the same full text search performs far worse (4 orders of magnitude) when searching on only one word ("yorkie" in this example):

```sql
explain analyze
SELECT * FROM "posts"
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', posts.title) @@ websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'yorkie')
ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1000.45..9190.19 rows=100 width=712) (actual time=2594.425..33396.395 rows=56 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.45..1032415.71 rows=12594 width=712) (actual time=2594.392..33396.242 rows=56 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using index_posts_on_created_at on posts  (cost=0.43..1029962.02 rows=5248 width=712) (actual time=1487.382..28371.694 rows=19 loops=3)
               Filter: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, (title)::text) @@ '''yorkie'''::tsquery)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 839536
 Planning Time: 4.079 ms
 Execution Time: 33397.521 ms
```

The second example is performing worse because PostgreSQL's query planner isn't choosing to use the `posts_title_simple_gin` index.  For now, our workaround hack is to duplicate the text in a single word search before running the SQL query, but that feels like randomly poking my finger into a black box.

Other information:

- 56 rows are matched in either of the above queries
- 2,518,663 rows are in the `posts` table
- Performance is similar using `to_tsquery` instead of `websearch_to_tsquery`
- With the `order by` clause removed the GIN index *is* used and performance is good
- PostgreSQL 12.9

Relevant portions of the [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) for the `posts` table:

```
\d posts
                                                 Table "public.posts"
            Column            |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default
------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id                           | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title                        | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 created_at                   | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_posts_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "posts_title_simple_gin" gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, title::text))
```

`pg_stats` data for the `posts_title_simple_gin` index:
https://gist.github.com/noahfpf/6742aa54bcb509aa1651c5b69debdfdb

Comment: What stats does the pg_stats view have for this table and row?

Comment: That should be "table name and attribute name (column name)", not  "table and row" which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- this is a query across all the rows in the `posts` table, so there's not one row in particular that's relevant.  I've added `pg_stats` info for the two columns referenced in the query.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question.  Since this is a functional index, you need to probe pg_stats differently, using the name of the index not the name of the table.  So `WHERE tablename='posts_title_simple_gin'`.

Comment: Did you ANALYZE the table after you created the index?

Comment: @jjanes, I've added stats for the `posts_title_simple_gin` index (in a linked gist).

We did not run `ANALYZE`, and after reading up on it I see that's the problem.  I've run it now, and the FTS query with a single word is using the correct GIN index, and running as quickly as expected.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This performance issue is because of searching for a single word, the query might end up scanning a significant portion of the table.

Do you tried to make index for column `title` using a full text search index. Then, like you did here in title column Use the tsvector data type for the indexed column and the tsquery type for the search query.

Also search for trigram indexes. Then analyze the query to see the performance

Comment: The `posts.title` column is indexed: "posts_title_simple_gin" gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, title::text)).  That's why the search for "yorkie yorkie" is fast.

Comment: Maybe ElasticSearch can be used